# How do you stop people from asking and answering their own questions en masse?

Tags: support, questions, answers

How do you stop people from asking and answering their own questions en masse?

Comment: Like what is density times volume?

Comment: Sometimes you find the answer before anyone else does. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Well, I imagine the priest might have a problem if they're doing it on mass ... But that's really between the two of them. :) (Sorry, couldn't resist. I'm fixing that spelling to en masse.)

Comment: My comment isn't funny anymore =[

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You do realize that..

- you have to wait 2 days to accept your own answer
- you don't get any rep for accepting your own answer

Beyond that, is this really a problem *in practice* and not just *in theory*?

Comment: You don't have to wait if you've set the bounty and it expires within that 2 day waiting period. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26305/why-dont-stack-overflow-users-still-know-how-to-close-questions-appropriately

Comment: @random: you have even less to win (and more to lose) by winning your own bounty.

Comment: You answer your own question if no one else can and then the question is answered for everyone. if the question cant be answered and then you find the answer, then you have a very good question that you have just answered. WTF!

Answer (score 7):

What's wrong with people answering their own questions?

OP stands no gain to answer their own question, other than to share with the community. You get no reputation for answering your own question.

Comment: Well I think that some people might think they are entitled to the reputation for the "correct" answer, and the OP reposts the correct answer and accepts his own.

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the spirit of The Trilogy and only hurt the OP?

Comment: Good point. I would upvote your answer but something is preventing me from doing so.

Comment: you mean if the OP accepts his own answer, they don't get +10 for accepted answeR?

Comment: @snicker: *now* you look a bit schizophrenic, talking to yourself that way :)

Answer (score 3):

By design, it's always been OK to ask a question and answer it yourself. One of the first SO questions I ever asked I did exactly that.

That said, over time, the social mores have changed a bit, and it's at least considered better form if you mark your own answer as community wiki such that you don't get rep from it.

In my opinion, this isn't a big issue. Other answers can come up and be just as good, and voted just as highly. It's not like the OP posting his own answer prevents others from posting theirs. And if theirs are better, the community will reward them.

Answer (score 1):

in theory, i'm not even sure this would be a Bad Thing

in practice, it is never going to happen because Jon Skeet will answer the questions *en masse* before the masses can